# Delphi DBExpress with Devart SQL Server driver how to connect to database

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I have installed the trial version of devart sql-server driver for dbexpress. But I have little Idea how to set-up the driver properties in order to connect. I want to connect to the SqlServer express instance on my pc, with windows authorization but I cannot figure out how to set the parameters in the TSqlConnection component. I assume hostname is the name of the server, but how do I set the authorization mode? When I activate the connection it keeps asking me with username and password. Sorry maybe I am asking something obvious but please help me to start up with my SqL server connection. Thanks

Comment: Has the connection object a property like `Authentication`? You should try to get the documentation for this product, establishing connections is one point that is usually documented pretty well.

Comment: Hi I have found the documentation, but cannot find explained a way to use Windows authentication

Comment: There are various fields like:
DSAuthScheme, DSAuthuser, etc.. but do not know how to use

Comment: Are there alternatives to devart, preferably free? I made a search and this seems the only product I could come to.

Comment: I use Devart's SQLServer driver. To login with Windows Authentication, simply don't set a username and password at all. It will then login as the user of the calling thread when connecting. As for a (free) alternative, I'm not aware of any (I've been looking), unless you write your own